# Prove that a finite-rank operator $ A $ on Hilbert space satisfies $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty ||Ae_n||^2 < \infty $, where $ (e_n)_n $ is the ONB for $ H $.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm stuck with the problem in the title. My source mentions "Hilbert-Schmidt" operator properties, but I wasn't able to deduce how that helps (or proves) the problem above.

Comment: Rank $0$ is trivial, so start looking at the case of rank $1$. Can you describe rank-$1$ operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite-rank operator $A$ can be written as $$A = \sum_{m=1}^N \lambda_m\langle \cdot, f_m\rangle g_m$$ for some orthonormal $\{f_m\}$ and $\{g_m\}$, where $\lambda_m$ are the singular values of $A$. Then, $$\| Ae_n\|^2 = \sum_{m=1}^N \lvert \lambda_m\langle e_n, f_m\rangle\rvert^2$$ by the orthonormality of the $g_m$.Then, the problem inequality becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^N \lvert \lambda_m\langle e_n, f_m\rangle\rvert^2 = \sum_{m=1}^N\lvert \lambda_m\rvert^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert \langle e_n, f_m\rangle\rvert^2\leq \sum_{m=1}^N\lvert \lambda_m\rvert^2\|f_m\|^2 = \sum_{m=1}^N \lvert \lambda_m\rvert^2 < \infty$$ by Bessel's inequality.